# What is the meaning of the expression ${variable_name} in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-templates

I know the dollar sign `$` refers to the `jQuery` object but I don't know that the curly braces `{}` that follow do.

Is `${variable_name}` referring to a `jQuery` attribute?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**${} Template Tag :-**
Used for insertion of data values in the rendered template. Evaluates the specified field (property) on the current data item, or the specified JavaScript function or expression.

more details here

http://api.jquery.com/template-tag-equal/

Comment: Huh... What do you know. I thought it was just a syntax error. +1