# The ${n: in jQuery

Tags: jquery, plugins, bundle, aptana, code-assist

I use Aptana to write JS and I recently installed jQuery bundle (mostly for code-completion but also for new cool things that I do not know).

So when I type `ready` and press `Ctrl + <Space>` I get two options, `document ready` and `document ready (safe)` choosing one of which will automatically put `$(document).ready(function(){})` or `jQuery(document).ready(function($){})` respectively.

But that is irrelevant. When I use `$(someElement).cl` the code-completion feature gives me the option `click` and when I select it it puts down the following code for me:

```
$(someElement).click(function() {
  ${0:
\}});
```

(It's relevant. I'll talk about it later)

Similarly, I was trying to write a plugin and I typed `plugin` and pressed `Ctrl + <Space>` and selecting the option `plugin (method)` I got the following code:

```
;(function($) {
}
$.fn.pluginName = function(options) {
  var opts = $.extend({}, $.fn.pluginName.defaults, options);

  return this.each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);

    ${6:
    var o = $.meta ? $.extend({\}, opts, $this.data()) : opts;
  }

  });

  // private function for debugging
  function debug($obj) {
    if (window.console && window.console.log) {
      window.console.log($obj);
    }
  }
};

// default options
$.fn.pluginName.defaults = {
  defaultOne:true,
  defaultTwo:false,
  defaultThree:'yay!'
};

})(jQuery);
```

First of all, as far as I know, a common method of writing a plugin goes like this

```
(function($) {
   $.fn.plugin = function(args) {
      //...
   }
})(jQuery);
```

And I can define `defaults` as `$.fn.plugin.defaults = {...}` or just `var defaults = {...}` inside my plugin and in my plugin, extend a `{}` with `defaults` and `args`. That's just about all I am familiar with.

So:

- Why does Aptana jQuery bundle put a `;` in the very beginning?
- Why does it close the `function($){}` before `$.fn.pluginName`?
- And most of all, what is this `${0:` in the `$.click()` example and `${6:` in `plugin (method)` example?
- Also, what indeed is `$.meta` and `$this.data()`?

It's all very confusing (yet, strangely exciting)...

Answer (score 1):

- The semicolon before the self-invoking function is protection against
  previous, potentially unterminated code:
  http://debuggable.com/posts/how-to-write-jquery-plugins:4f72ab2e-7310-4a74-817a-0a04cbdd56cb
- I imagine they close the `function($){}` before the `$.fn.pluginName` so that the `$.fn.pluginName` is available outside of the scope of the self-invoked `function($){}`
- Could not find and answer for this `${number: var...` notation - hopefully someone can help us out here. The only thing I can find in jQuery that uses `${}` is templating: [What is the meaning of the expression ${variable_name} in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6978630/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-expression-variable-name-in-jquery)
- `$this.data()` would just return the contents of the element that `this.each(function(){})` is being applied to: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/. Say you had several `p`'s with a class of 'myPars' and you had:

  $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.myPars').pluginName();
  })

Then each `p` of that class would get a copy of that function and `$this.data()` would contain the contents of whichever `p` is currently "this"

I'm no jQuery expert, so I hope better informed individuals are around to help with things I couldn't explain well.